# Nested element search in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery and jQuery ui. Below is my markup:

```
<div id="content">   
   <ul id="sortable">             
    <li class="button_tab"><div id="select_me">Select Me</div></li>
    <li class="button_tab"><div id="select_me_1">Select Me 1</div></li>
    <li class="button_tab"><div id="select_me_2">Select Me 2</div></li>           
  </ul>  
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $( ".button_tab" ).button();
```

I am trying to get the id="select_me" on click event, but nothing happens, because the button() function inserts specific class name and i can't select it right:

```
 $('div#content ul#sortable li.button_tab div').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));        
 });
```

Comment: seems like it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/mvg4E/

Comment: working fine for me too http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/zQp5L/ are you getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is happening, what exactly do you see, any error or what ?

Comment: works for me too - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ZQw8V/

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla i don't know what you did to yours but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @mcgrailm I just checked your fiddle and it was working, may be you could not see the li items turning into buttons, but the event still fires

Comment: It's not coz of that. :-). The sequence of firing matters. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given code works fine. However the sequence of calling them matters.

`.button()`  will clear out all `click` events since it is logically supposed to handle 'clicks' . So for enabling custom `click` events again for the children. You have to create a `click` event listener after calling `.button()`

1. `$( ".button_tab" ).button();`
2. `$('div#content ul#sortable li.button_tab div').click(function() {
          alert($(this).attr('id'));

        });`

Or else, You can make use of `.on()`  and create a dynamic `click` event listener in Jquery.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you, i was doing the opposite way in my code.

Comment: @johnnyj  :-) . You can implement `.on()` for `click` event  if you absolutely want the dynamic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#sortable li.button_tab div[id^='button_tab']").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));        
});
```

OR

```
$("#sortable li.button_tab").click(function() {
   var div_id = $(this).find("div[id^='button_tab']").attr("id");
   alert(div_id);        
});
```